# Grouping ListView by Property of ViewModel in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, grouping

I have a problem that is not addressed by the numerous articles on MVVM grouping that I have read.

I am writing a WPF application. Here are some excepts from classes that are relevant to my question - first the MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Recipe_OverViewModel> RecipeOverViews {get ; set;}

....[omitted extraneous lines]....
```

The class that is used as the observable collection of Recipes in the MainViewModel:

```
public class Recipe_OverViewModel
{
    public Recipe TargetRecipe { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TargetRecipe.Parent_Name;
    }

....[omitted extraneous lines]....
```

and The Class that is taken from the database, that is the actual Recipe

```
public partial class Recipe
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Parent_Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Recipe_Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Parent_Name;
    }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return Parent_Name.CompareTo(((Recipe)obj).Parent_Name);
    }

 ....[omitted extraneous lines]....
```

Each class has more properties and methods and so on, but these are enough to explain what I am asking.

The `Recipe_OverViewModel` is the view model for a control (`Recipe_OverView`) that displays the properties of the recipe. In the `MainViewModel`, I have the following xaml (extracted from the larger file):

```
<Window x:Class="RecipeApp.UI.MainWindow"

....[omitted extraneous lines]....

    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:RecipeApp.UI.ViewModel"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Recipe_OverViewModel}" x:Key="Recipe_DT" x:Name="Recipe_DT">
        <control:Recipe_OverView Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=ListWidth}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedRecipeOverViews" Source="{Binding RecipeOverViews}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="TargetRecipe"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="TargetRecipe"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

....[omitted extraneous lines]....

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedRecipeOverViews}}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Recipe_DT}">
                 </ListView>
```

This list view correctly displays the list of recipes in the listview, with each row containing the `Recipe_OverView` control. However, I cannot get the grouping to work correctly. I would like to group the listview by the Parent_Name property of the Recipe associated with each `Recipe_OverViewModel`. My attempt looked like this, following the [Microsoft HowTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-items-in-a-listview-that-implements-a-gridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

```
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedRecipeOverViews}}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Recipe_DT}"
                     >
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="true">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ParentName}" />
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
```

However, all I get from that is as many empty (no ParentName populated) headers as there are recipes in the collection and a Binding Failure that tells me the "ParentName property not found on object of type CollectionViewGroupInternal." I get the expander buttons, but there is nothing within the expanded groups:

[image: Empty Headers]

I thought I understand that that means that the binding is looking in the `Recipe_OverViewModel` for the ParentName property, but even when I added this as a property in the `Recipe_OverViewModel` and populated it, I still got this error, so now I am confused and have the following questions:

Where is the binding on the ListView actually looking?
How should I direct it to look at the `Recipe_OverViewModel.TargetRecipe.ParentName` (or is it impossible)?

I would really appreciate help on this matter, so many articles take so much simpler examples, and I cannot work out how to extend it to my case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the binding on the `ListView` actually looking?

It looks for a property of the `CollectionViewGroupInternal` class.

This class has a `Name` property that returns the value of the property that you group by, i.e. `TargetRecipe`, and an `Items` property that returns the collection of objects that belongs to the current group.

So, if I understand your setup correctly, you could try to bind to the `Parent_Name` property of the first item in the group:

```
<Expander.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].Parent_Name}" />
</Expander.Header>
```

Comment: This works to show the header and adding `<Expander.Content><ItemsPresenter/></Expander.Content>` after the Header fixes the display of the items - The Microsoft grouping example does not include the contents of each group!

Answer (score 1):

The ItemsSource is bound to the SortedRecipeOverViews, which in turn is bound to the RecipeOverViews collection.
The item type of this collection is Recipe_OverViewModel.
And this type doesn't have a ParentName property.
There is a Parent_Name property, BUT not in the Recipe_OverViewModel type, but in the Recipe type.
And the Recipe_OverViewModel type has a property of this type.
In general, you have some kind of mess of types, their names and their properties, binding paths.
Perhaps you copied something wrong into the topic?

Based on my own guess, try applying a binding like this:

```
 <Expander.Header>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TargetRecipe.Parent_Name}" />
 </Expander.Header>
```

Comment: Sorry, the ParentName was left over from me adding this as a property of the Recipe_OverViewModel directly, which didn't help either. Sadly, your suggestion gives the same result - nothing inside the headers. I do understand what you mean about the mess of types and names... Not sure how to avoid it in this case - ViewModel contains a collection of ViewModels that contain the database class at the heart.

Comment: It's best if you create a minimal reproducible example and give it.
Can be archived or on GitHub.
Since it is impossible to reproduce your problem according to your codes in the topic.

Comment: Right. I will add one tomorrow; I'm about to go home right now. I think the problem is as much that the groups are all empty as it is that I can't seem to bind to get the title of each group.